# Decode QR from image (or how to run Exec in a loop)

Tags: windows, command-line, perl

I need to decode a folder full of QR code from image files. After A LOT of research, I finally found a libary that works on Windows. Not my ideal choice (Zbar won't install on Strawberry PERL as "...can't include zbar and zbar.h" ... or on my online account where it says it needs a working C: compiler. Other options haven't been updated in years, or require other libraries such as DecodeQR requires OpenCV / compilers etc, or libdecodeqr which I think needs a compiler rather than Windows/Perl)

Don't worry: Question coming in a moment.

At least Zbar for Windows seems to be contained in a single (portable: path dependant) folder, although I don't  know whether the installer placed files in registry.  I should add at this point that - if Windows based - the program is to be passed to others to use. If I can get a version to work on server it doesn't matter what files I have to install ... providing they work!)

Anyway ...

This is being executed from VBScript. I've managed to get the image files into a folder object which I then reiterate through. This is my code:

```
For Each f in PicFiles
   Set out=objShell.Exec("C:\EventProc\Zbar\bin\zbarimg -D -q " &f)
   tmp=out.StdOut.ReadAll
   MsgBox(tmp)
Next
```

In Zbar parlance, the flags mean (-D :Don't display the decoded barcode image) and (-q: only show the decoded output to console window)

At present, this arrangement means that the console window flashes open and rapidly closes again on each loop. (The shell doesn't release the value to Stdout until it closes) This could be "rather annoying" when going through 200+ image files!!

I did try "Run" rather than "Exec", but of course that doesn't return any value to Stdout or to a variable!

I tried adding ",0" after "&f" in an attempt to create a hidden window ... but then
a) either it treats it as part of the filename and cannot render -or-
b) because it's hidden, no value gets reported to StdOut
either way, the tmp string is blank.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Open a file, and get DetailsA
   Read folder of images
        For
        "decodeQR" is code within image (ideally silently)
        Next
 Append "decodedQR |DetailsA" to an external file
```

** I've no problem opening / writing files. The problem is the flashing window - unless there is a completely different option

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it sorted. I didn't need to use a "for next" loop; I simply made the file ref a wildcard, and it scans for all jpg images in folder. I then take the XML data, and read through to find the filename of pic / QR code which I write out to a  file.

One prob. Due to exec, you can't hide the console window.

Here is the Zbarimg code used:

```
xml_data=createobject("wscript.Shell").exec("C:\MobiEvent\Zbar\bin\zbarimg -D -q --xml C:\MobiEvent\AllPics\*.jpg").stdout.readall
test=Split(xml_data,vbLf)
```

The -D stops it displaying the barcode image, the -q outputs the bacic info and -xml exports the XML data to the STDOUT which is fed into "xml_data" That's then split into an array, and I go through it line by line to find the QR code ref / image file name which are written to a file.